# array index out of bound for append array result into java text area

Tags: java, arrays

I have two program which are SocketServer and MyNoteCenter. Every time the user click the download button,it will send to the SocketServer for storing. The user can retrieve their record by click the show button to show the record. After that, append to the text area but unfortunately I get an ArrayOutOfBound error for my code. The errors show me that the display method in MyNoteCenter and show method in SocketServer method. I had search a lot of solution on my problem but it still look the same and I checked the array index was enough to hold 5 data. The 5 data will bring to the SocketServer by using the parameter constructor when certain function being invoke at MyNoteCenter

MyNoteCenter program(portion)

```
  if(e.getSource()==btn3)
    {
        String  [] ds = new String[5];
        ds = display();
        for(int i = 0; i <=ds.length;i++)
         {
            ta1.append("Result"+i+":"+ds[i]);
         }
    }
    public String[] display()
       {
         SocketServer ds = new SocketServer();
         String [] STRarr = new String[5];
         STRarr[5] = ds.show();
         return STRarr;
       }
```

SocketServer program(portion)

```
public SocketServer(String selection,String id,String name,String year,String major) //The constructor accept the value from user and store it, it's being implement at others function  
{
 this.selection = selection;
 this.name = name;  
 this.id = id ;
 this.year = year ;
 this.major = major ;
}
public String show()
{
    String [] arr = new String[5];
    arr[0] = name;
    arr[1] = id;
    arr[2] = year;
    arr[3] = major;
    arr[4] = selection;
    counter++;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You are in" +counter);
    return arr[5];

}
```

Comment: In SocketServer class...show method you are trying to return arr[5]...which is giving error as your array size is 5 arr[0]..to arr[4] same goes for display method as well STRarr[5]  is not possible

Comment: the array index need to reduce to 4 ?

Comment: as you have defined array size to be 5, hence possible indexes are 0,1,2,3,4 other then this it will throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException. So now depending upon requirement return that index which will be within bound. Also do change in the conditional statement of for loop as mention by@camickr

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i <=ds.length;i++)
```

The standard looping construct is to NOT use the "=" in the looping condition since indexes in Java are 0 based. The code should be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < ds.length; i++)
```

Don't be afraid to use white space when coding. It is easier to spot the test condition when it is separated by spaces.

Edit:

```
return arr[5];
```

You can't hardcode 5. The only valid indexes are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.

Why are you creating an Array with 5 values and then only returning a single String? The other 4 values will be lost.

Maybe you need to return the entire array:

```
public String[] show()

...

return arr;
```

Comment: i try edit according to your guide but I still get the same error...  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
 5
        at SocketServer.show(SocketServer.java:117)
        at MyNoteCenter.display(MyNoteCenter.java:235)
        at MyNoteCenter.actionPerformed(MyNoteCenter.java:213)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2
22)                                                                                                                this is the error message I get

Comment: Somewhere in your code you are still trying to access index "5". Fix the code. We can't do the debugging for you. See edit for possible problem.